# What's a good technique for cooking fresh corn in the microwave?

Tags: microwave, corn

What techniques for cooking fresh corn in the microwave give good results? Should I peel it, should I add water, salt, butter, etc.

Comment: I can't imagine throwing an ear of corn into the microwave because it is so good and easy to boil in water. Boil it (sans husk) for about 20 minutes and let each person add butter, salt, and pepper to taste. yummmmmm!

Comment: 20 minutes? Five works for me.

Comment: @Ben : if you're cooking for 1, and it's the middle of the summer (and you don't want to further heat up the house), the microwave is your friend.

Comment: I honestly have no clue how long to boil corn, but I know that I've boiled it for 20 minutes with great results.  5 minutes probably will work just as well :-).

Comment: @Joe Good point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done it in the husk, when it's fresh (ie, the husk isn't dried out), but I don't like the grassy flavors that the husk imparts.

My neighbor's clued me into a box of dry wax paper sheets to cover food for the microwave (so I can be lazy and not have to clean the microwave as often), so I wrap the corn in it after it's been husked and the silk removed.  I just roll in around the corn, twist the ends like the paper wrapping on taffy, then microwave it for a few seconds.

I haven't done it recently, so I can't remember exact times (and the wattage of microwaves differ, anyway) ... you just want to warm it through, though.  If you were going to try to get it hot, I'd consider dropping to medium power for a much longer time, so you don't overly cook the outside, as I vaguely recall having an incident once.

Comment: That is exactly how I do it -- husk and remove silk, then wrap in wax paper. Place in microwave and cook for about 3 to 5 minutes for the first ear, with an additional 2 minutes or so for each additional ear, or until they give gently when you squeeze them (through a towel or oven mitt, since they'll be hot). Unwrap and serve.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap in wet paper towel and microwave for no more than 5 minutes for 2 cobs, 3 minutes for 1